# Проблема с работой google tag manager

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, gtm

http://pokritijametallov.ru/ 
Существует проект на котором появилась проблема подключения GTM.
(ранее с ним(GTM) не работал.)
При попытке подключить данный модуль 3-мя способами:
1.https://github.com/nuxt-community/gtm-module
(в данном случае пробовал 2 разные версии плагина.)

2.(Этот способ реализован на текущей версии проекта.)
[image]

3.[image]

Получаю после деплоя один и тот же баг:
Заключается он в том что GTM отслеживает страницы только при первом посещении ресурса или же после перезагрузки страницы в браузере(с обновлением кэша).
При переходе на остальные страницы отслеживание не работает.
Первое что приходит на ум - это причина в `nuxt-link`-ах, по которым собственно происходит переход на остальные страницы.
В фаербаге в сети так же можно увидеть, что никакой загрузки GTM не происходит после переходов по внутренним линкам.

Вопрос:
В чем может быть проблема и как ее решить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо в настройки добавить правильный eventName который настраивается в аналитике, в моем случае это:

```
gtm: {pageViewEventName: 'page_view',},
```